# PDO is inserting ids into database instead of names

Tags: javascript, php, html

So i'm a little confused here, i made two dropdowns and they are working. The problem is that when i insert the data i get into the table the ids of the dropdown elements instead of their name. I'm pretty sure i need to do it in another way but i'm an amateur so any explanation will be apreciate.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0)
    {   
header('location:index.php');
}
else{
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$id=null;
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$user=$_POST['user'];
$password=md5($_POST['password']);
$mobileno=$_POST['mobileno'];
$bloc=$_POST['industry_name'];
$apartament=$_POST['sub_industry_name'];
$intretinere=$_POST['intretinere'];
$m2=$_POST['m2'];

$notitype='Create Account';
$reciver='Admin';
$sender=$email;

$sqlnoti="insert into notification (notiuser,notireciver,notitype) values (:notiuser,:notireciver,:notitype)";
$querynoti = $dbh->prepare($sqlnoti);
$querynoti-> bindParam(':notiuser', $sender, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$querynoti-> bindParam(':notireciver',$reciver, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$querynoti-> bindParam(':notitype', $notitype, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$querynoti->execute();    

$sql ="INSERT INTO users(id, name, email, user, password, mobile, bloc, apartament, intretinere, m2, status) VALUES(:id, :name, :email, :user, :password, :mobileno, :industry_name, :sub_industry_name, :intretinere, :m2, 1)";
$query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query-> bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query-> bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query-> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query-> bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query-> bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query-> bindParam(':mobileno', $mobileno, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query-> bindParam(':industry_name', $bloc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query-> bindParam(':sub_industry_name', $apartament, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query-> bindParam(':intretinere', $intretinere, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query-> bindParam(':m2', $m2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
if($lastInsertId)
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Registration Sucessfull!');</script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'adduser.php'; </script>";
}
else 
{
$error="Something went wrong. Please try again";
}

}
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#category_item').selectpicker();

  $('#sub_category_item').selectpicker();

  load_data('category_data');

  function load_data(type, category_id = '')
  {
    $.ajax({
      url:"../admin/load_data.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{type:type, category_id:category_id},
      dataType:"json",
      success:function(data)
      {
        var html = '';
        for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
        {
          html += '<option value="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].name+'</option>';
        }
        if(type == 'category_data')
        {
          $('#category_item').html(html);
          $('#category_item').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
        else
        {
          $('#sub_category_item').html(html);
          $('#sub_category_item').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).on('change', '#category_item', function(){
    var category_id = $('#category_item').val();
    load_data('sub_category_data', category_id);
  });

});
</script>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Bloc<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<select name="industry_name" id="category_item" class="form-control" required title="Selecteaza Bloc">
<option value="">Selecteaza Bloc</option>
</select>
</div>
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Apartament<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<select name="sub_industry_name" id="sub_category_item" class="form-control" required data-live-search="true" title="Selecteaza Apartament">
<option value="">Selecteaza Apartament</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Also load_data.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include('includes/config.php');

if(isset($_POST["type"]))
{
 if($_POST["type"] == "category_data")
 {
  $query = "
  SELECT * FROM tbl_industry 
  ORDER BY industry_name ASC
  ";
  $statement = $dbh->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute();
  $data = $statement->fetchAll();
  foreach($data as $row)
  {
   $output[] = array(
    'id'  => $row["industry_id"],
    'name'  => $row["industry_name"]
   );
  }
  echo json_encode($output);
 }
 else
 {
  $query = "
  SELECT * FROM tbl_sub_industry 
  WHERE industry_id = '".$_POST["category_id"]."' 
  ORDER BY sub_industry_name ASC
  ";
  $statement = $dbh->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute();
  $data = $statement->fetchAll();
  foreach($data as $row)
  {
   $output[] = array(
    'id'  => $row["sub_industry_id"],
    'name'  => $row["sub_industry_name"]
   );
  }
  echo json_encode($output);
 }
}

?>
```

EDIT: I have updated the code folowing the answer below but now i don't get anything in the dropdowns.

Here is the js:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#category_item').selectpicker();

  $('#sub_category_item').selectpicker();

  load_data('category_data');

  function load_data(type, category_id = '')
  {
    $.ajax({
      url:"../admin/load_data.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{type:type, category_id:category_id},
      dataType:"json",
      success:function(data)
      {
        var html = '';
        for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
        {
    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
    html += '<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>';
    });

        }
        if(type == 'category_data')
        {
          $('#category_item').html(html);
          $('#category_item').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
        else
        {
          $('#sub_category_item').html(html);
          $('#sub_category_item').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).on('change', '#category_item', function(){
    var category_id = $('#category_item').val();
    load_data('sub_category_data', category_id);
  });

});
</script>
```

And load_data.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include('includes/config.php');

if(isset($_POST["type"]))
{
 if($_POST["type"] == "category_data")
 {
  $query = "
  SELECT * FROM tbl_industry 
  ORDER BY industry_name ASC
  ";
  $statement = $dbh->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute();
  $data = $statement->fetchAll();
  foreach($data as $row){
  $output[$row["industry_id"]] = $row["industry_name"];
}
  echo json_encode($output);
 }
 else
 {
  $query = "
  SELECT * FROM tbl_sub_industry 
  WHERE industry_id = '".$_POST["category_id"]."' 
  ORDER BY sub_industry_name ASC
  ";
  $statement = $dbh->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute();
  $data = $statement->fetchAll();
  foreach($data as $row){
  $output[$row["sub_industry_id"]] = $row["sub_industry_name"];
}
  echo json_encode($output);
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @JayBlanchard, i just took a look over the documentation links you have suggested and i will definetly try to change the way i hash the passwords. But first i would like to solve the goal regarding my question.

Comment: That's a lot of code. What have you tried to spot the point where it's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You say you're inserting the IDs of the items in the dropdown, because that's what you're setting in `load_data()`.

Instead of

```
 html += '<option value="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].name+'</option>';
```

Try

```
 html += '<option value="'+data[count].name+'">'+data[count].name+'</option>';
```

Unless you manipulate the data before your AJAX call, `$_POST` will take the `value` from the `option` tag, rather than the text displayed between the opening and closing tags.

You're adding unnecessary steps when creating and reading your arrays. In `load_data`, you can create arrays with a key based on your result:

```
foreach($data as $row){
   $output[$row["industry_id"]] = $row["industry_name"];
}
```

Then use jQuery's `$.each` function to read the data after your AJAX call:

```
$.each( data, function( key, value ) {
   html += '<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>';
});
```

See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: My bad, i forgot to also add that part of the code and i just edited my question. I also tried your suggestion but using that won't show the name of the elements in the second dropdown.

Comment: I updated my answer including your data format. Did this solve the issue?

Comment: Sorry @user1517599 but unfortunately i didn't got the chance to try it today yet.